# How to map an object to form fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an object like this:

```
var settings = {
    Name: "Fairy Tail",
    Feature:
    {
        Translate: true,
        Share: true
    }
}
```

And a form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Feature.Translate" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Feature.Share" />
</form>
```

How can I make the object fill the form "automatically" (without setting the value of each field by hand)?

Comment: what is your backend , this is called reflection in c# atleast , i have never done at UI or jquery level

Comment: It has to be on javascript. I am using it on an addon.

Comment: What, if any, frameworks are available (jQuery, Dojo, etc..) ?

Comment: @jdc jQuery (look at the tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WY5rT/2/) for a **more sophisticated example**), assuming you have `settings` variable set first:

```
var assignValue = function(n, v){
    var field = jQuery('form input[name="'+n+'"]');
    if (field.attr('type')=='text'){
        field.val(v);
    } else if (field.attr('type')=='checkbox') {
        field.prop('checked',v);
    }
}

var assignSettings = function(list, prefix){
    if (typeof prefix != 'undefined'){
        prefix += '.';
    }else{
        prefix = '';
    }
    for (item in list){
        if ((typeof list[item]=='string')||(typeof list[item]=='boolean')){
            assignValue(prefix+item,list[item]);
        }else if(typeof list[item]=='object'){
            var n1 = item;
            assignSettings(list[n1],prefix+n1);
        }
    }
}

assignSettings(settings);
```

And this solution is not as limited as other solutions in the versions I have seen so far - it supports the case you have given and can be easily expanded to support different types of fields and more levels.

Answer (score 2):

```
var inputs = $('form input[type="checkbox"]');

$.each(settings.Feature, function(key, val) {
    inputs.filter('[name="Feature.' + key + '"]')[0].checked = val;
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9z928/

---

If you also wanted the text field filled in:

```
var inputs = $('form input');

inputs.first().val( settings.Name );

$.each(settings.Feature, function(key, val) {
    inputs.filter('[name="Feature.' + key + '"]')[0].checked = val;
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9z928/1/

Comment: What if I have a different structure, or more objects like `Feature`? How can I make it work with any object?

Comment: @BrunoLM: Will the naming be consistent, so that each key like `Feature` will be associated with a `name` attribute starting with that same key? `Feature === Feature.xxxxx`

Comment: The naming will always match with the object structure. `{ Something: { Debug: true, Mode: { Max: true } } }` will have a field named `Something.Debug` and `Something.Mode.Max` and so on. Only leaf nodes are fields.

Comment: @BrunoLM: Ah, so there can be deep nesting. That will best be done with recursion if you don't know in advance how deeply the nesting goes. I'll update in a minute.

Comment: @BrunoM: This solution will work if you have `Name` key in your `settings` variable and the first input in the form will be the one with `name="Name"` attribute. Otherwise it will fail. It will also fail if you have multiple checkboxes with the same names.

Comment: @BrunoLM: What is known? The code in your comment no longer has a `Name`. The best solution will depend on the actual requirements.

Comment: @patrick dw: Please see my answer - this should meet your needs. If not, provide your feedback about "why it does not meet your needs".

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth giving this a try: http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JavaScript library for mapping Obeject to form fields name and vice versa.
[Object-Form-Mapping](http://javascriptmanagement.blogspot.com/2011/06/form-management.html)